Entry to only accept hex values
Trying to create an Entry box that only allows hexadecimal values to be entered.
I've tried the below, but as soon as non hex is entered, I get errors.
class HexEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self.var = StringVar()
        Entry.__init__(self, master, textvariable=self.var, **kwargs)
        self.old_value = ''
        self.var.trace('w', self.check)

    def check(self, *args):
        current_value = self.var.get()
        if (int(current_value,16)):
            self.old_value = current_value
        elif current_value == "":
            self.old_value = current_value
        else:
            self.var.set(self.old_value)


int() isn't a boolean function. It converts the string to an integer and returns that value, it doesn't test if it's a valid integer. It will be False if the integer is 0.

Check my edited answer now. Mine will be much simpler and useful.

This seems to work OK.
class HexEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self.var = StringVar()
        Entry.__init__(self, master, textvariable=self.var, **kwargs)
        self.old_value = ''
        self.var.trace('w', self.check)

    def check(self, *args):
        current_value = self.var.get()
        try:
            if (int(current_value,16)):
                self.old_value = current_value
            elif current_value == "":
                self.old_value = current_value
        except:
            self.var.set(self.old_value)

I finished up with this as a working demo of getting hex string input & displaying in a text box (I didn't use TTK in the end):
(Thanks for the help to all who contributed). 
from tkinter import *
from re import fullmatch

def validate(value: str) -> bool:  # validation functions must return True or False
    pattern = '[a-fA-F0-9]*'  # match 0 or more hexadecimal digits
    return bool(fullmatch(pattern, value))

def Get_Key():
    mykey=my_entry.get()
    # Clear the key entry, clear the text box, write key to text box
    my_entry.delete(0,65)
    text_box.delete('1.0', END)
    text_box.insert('1.0',mykey)
    
root = Tk()
# '%P' is a special 'substitution' character for 'the value that was just entered';
# this is what gets passed to the 'validate' function
vcmd = (root.register(validate), '%P')
# setting validate='key' will trigger validation whenever a key is pressed
my_entry = Entry(root, width=80, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
my_entry.grid(row=0,column=0)

myButton = Button(root, text="Get & show key", relief=RAISED, bd=2, bg="lightblue", fg="blue", command = Get_Key)
myButton.grid(row=1,column=0)

text_box = Text(root, bg = "white", fg = "blue", bd = 2, height=16, width=80, relief = GROOVE, padx=5,pady=5)
text_box.grid(row=2,column=0)

root.mainloop()


The if statement isn't correct. It will treat the value 0 as False.

Why don't you just accept the answer from JRiggles?

This seems like a job for validation!
This example shows how to limit an Entry to only hexadecimal digits (a-f, A-F, and 0-9)
import tkinter as tk
from re import fullmatch
from tkinter import ttk


def validate(value: str) -> bool:  # validation functions must return True or False
    pattern = '[a-fA-F0-9]*'  # match 0 or more hexadecimal digits
    return bool(fullmatch(pattern, value))


root = tk.Tk()
# '%P' is a special 'substitution' character for 'the value that was just entered';
# this is what gets passed to the 'validate' function
vcmd = (root.register(validate), '%P')
# setting validate='key' will trigger validation whenever a key is pressed
entry = ttk.Entry(root, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()

If you want a reusable HexEntry class, the approach is similar
import tkinter as tk
from re import fullmatch
from tkinter import ttk


class HexEntry(ttk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent, validate='key')
        # we'll use winfo_toplevel here instead of root just in case this
        # widget's parent isn't the root window
        self.vcmd = (self.winfo_toplevel().register(self.validate), '%P')
        self.config(validatecommand=self.vcmd)

    def validate(self, value: str) -> bool:  
        pattern = '[a-fA-F0-9]*'  # match 0 or more hexadecimal digits
        return bool(fullmatch(pattern, value))


root = tk.Tk()

entry = HexEntry(root)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()


Edit: After seeing the OP's comment, this is my edited code. This code won't allow the user to type anything other than the hex keys.
Edit : Corrected code to add backspace, del, right arrow and left arrow keys as well.
from tkinter import *   


def on_key_press(evnt):
    allowed_chars = '0123456789abcdefABCDEF'
    allowed_keys = ['BackSpace', 'Delete', 'Left', 'Right']
    if evnt.char in allowed_chars or evnt.keysym in allowed_keys:
        return None
    else:
        return "break"  # Ignore the key press if it is not allowed 
    
    
        

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')

lbl = Label(root, text = 'Enter only hex values')
lbl.pack()

user_input = Entry(root)
user_input.pack()

#Bind user_input with "<KeyPress>" and the function on_key_press
user_input.bind("<KeyPress>", on_key_press)

root.mainloop()


Thanks, but not quite what I was after; I wanted an entry widget that would only accept hex chars & ignore/discard any non-hex chars typed.  I've got there now with StackOv help.

Do you want 'the ignoring portion' of the code?

@KevP, Check now. I've edited my answer. Hope this will be useful.

Your solution will also disable the backspace and delete keys.  Also constructing allowed_keys whenever the function is executed is not a good design and I don't understand why you don't simply use allowed_keys = "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef".

Actually, Intially I thought the numbers need to be typed not as strings, so I had a mindset of declaring it as a list only. So Not using allowed_keys = "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef" is just because of laziness towards typing it as list.  After seeing the error in the output, I changed the code to str(x) to list. So, it didn't strike to me that I can declare as string. Now after reading your comment only, It struck to me. Will change. Reg backspace, I'll check once again and edit.

@acw1668, Please check my edited code now and thanks for letting me know. Now it works as expected.

You could use a simple validation method such as
s = "A345"
import string
print(all(c in string.hexdigits for c in s))

I recommend also using a try except structure when a class instance is created, such as
try:
    #create class instance
except:
    print("No valid hexadecimal input received")

